# King and Three Knights v/s King in end game

Tags: knights, odds

Is it possible to checkmate with Three Knights and King v/s King in end game?

If yes, is this possible within 50 moves?

If no, Why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mate With 3 Knights](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/15674/mate-with-3-knights)

Answer (score 2):

Short Answer Yes.
2 Knights cannot mate but 3 knights can.
This is a duplicate question however: Please refer to [Mate With 3 Knights](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/15674/mate-with-3-knights)